# Generate code from user input

Tags: javascript, forms, textbox

I am trying to make a simple code generator using inputs added by the user.

It will go something like this:

"predefined code" + UserInput1 + "predefined code" + "UserInput2"

I assume I will need to assign variables to the UserInput which will change depending on what it writes in the text box.

I will need also a function that will show the output as I press the button in a text area

But I lack the skills to compose it since I'm a very started in JavaScript.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Be more specific. for example what would you like to do on the first input, and second input. what are you expecting from the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F9aQc/)**

```
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="button" value="See Code" onclick="magicCode();">


function magicCode() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hello " + document.getElementById("a").value + " Welcome " + document.getElementById("b").value;
}
```

Comment: While it's valid to use a number for the `id` in HTML5, it doesn't help readability or usefulness